# Is there any DataGridView Like control in MFC

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winforms, mfc

I want to create a Database application in MFC by using VS 2010 and i want to know is there any [.NET Winforms] DataGridView Like control in MFC.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kyh79x.aspx) to see how you can create MFC control from WinForms Control. Also [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/122771/DataGridView-VS2008-MFC) is the discussion about the issue.

Comment: I think that it won't be a managed application, but you will need such support for including the library although I'm not sure about that. I haven't seen such control in MFC or in MFC Feature Pack.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no built in solution from Microsoft. You will need to roll your own.  There are some pre-built solutions but I have never tried them.

https://www.google.com/search?q=MFC+datagrid&aq=f&oq=MFC+datagrid